# Code using the confluence API to display statistics about the pages in 1 given space

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api, scriptrunner-for-jira, confluence-macros

I would like to write some code in the scriptrunner console to display some statistics about the pages in a given confluence space. I would like to display the current info

```
"PageName;UserPageCreatorID;UserPageCreatorFullName;LastModificationDate\n"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Page
import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.PageManager
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor
import com.atlassian.sal.api.user.UserKey

SpaceManager spaceManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SpaceManager)
PageManager pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager)
UserAccessor userAccessor = ComponentLocator.getComponent(UserAccessor)

def file = new File('D:/confluence/data/scripts/result.groovy')
def fileWriter = new FileWriter(file) 

Space space = spaceManager.getSpace("IWIKI")
String result=""
result=result+"PageName;UserID;FullName;LastModificationDate\n"
for (Page page : pageManager.getPages(space, false)) {
    if(page.getCreator()==null){
            result=result+page.toString()+";null"+"\n"
    }
    else{
            String userID=page.getCreator().getName()
            String fullName =userAccessor.getUserByKey(page.getCreator().getKey()).getFullName()
            result=result+page.toString()+";"+userID+";"+fullName+";"+page.getLastModificationDate()+"\n"

    }

}
fileWriter.write(result)

fileWriter.close()
```